# plt::show() on macOS doesn't display anything, only a white blank screen

Tags: c++, macos, matplotlib

I used the minimal.cpp (snippet provided below)using the **matplotlib-cpp library** to display the plot but all I get to see is a blank white box with no plot. However I'm able to see the saved plot in the directory.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"

namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

int main()
{
    plt::plot({1,3,2,4});

    // save figure
    const char* filename = "./basic.png";
    std::cout << "Saving result to " << filename << std::endl;
    plt::save(filename);
    plt::show();
}

PS: I'm working from MacOSX environment and backend is TkAgg. 

My end goal is to use this library to plot a stream of data in realtime.
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example for us to replicate the issue.

Comment: Hi @Sailanarmo, I have updated the code snippet
Please let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks